# How can I replace char ↵ by a line-break in a text-binding?

Tags: javascript, css, knockout.js

I have a `<span data-bind="text: description"></span>` which is supposed to output

Store: Tailor Shop (1)
Send complete welcome package
Datasheet was completed at 01.01.2000

Instead the output looks like this (no line-breaks):

Store: Tailor Shop (1)  Send complete welcome package  Datasheet was completed at 01.01.2000

This is the data I get:

```
description: "
↵Store: Tailor Shop (1)
↵Send complete welcome package
↵Datasheet was completed at 01.01.2000"
```

How can I convert that char `↵` to a line-break using JS and CSS?

Following some answers I found here, I tried

```
description.replace("↵","\A")
```

and applying

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

To no avail.

Comment: A line break should be `"\n"` not `"\A"`.

Comment: That was my first shot of course - and it didn't work either.

Comment: To get a line break you can use <br/> or a block level html element. Newlines are ignored by html if not used inside <pre> tag.

Comment: text-binding in knockout strips out all HTML.

Comment: Are you sure that the `white-space` rule is applying to the right element? (Like, when you look at it with the DOM inspector, is the rule there?)

Comment: I have it inside the `span`'s style-attribute. So **yes** :)

Comment: @XPD See comment #4.

Comment: can you use html binding instead of text binding. If you can then you can use something like ko.description(text.replace('↵','<br/>'));

Comment: @XPD Sadly, the HTML element is not an option as it makes the page vulnerable to all sorts of script manipulation depending on the data I get.

Answer (score 0):

After many tries, thanks to XPD's comment, I found a working solution replacing the `span` by `pre`:

```
<pre style="font-family: Arial;" 
    data-bind="text: description.replace('↵','\n')">
</pre>
```

I applied arial as the standard font to make it not look like the mono fonted standard `<pre>` tag.